# Selenium does not find ChromeDriver on Windows10 (ruby)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on Windows 10, installed the Selenium gem, unzipped the ChromeDriver.exe to a folder in my PATH.

Yet, when I run some ruby code using Selenium with Chrome, that's what I get:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that Windows 10 doesn't like it, when ruby looks for a file in a system directory like \Windows\System32\ (file doesn't exist; try with: `File.exist?("path-to-chromedriver.exe")`, which returns: `false`). Probably a security issue, which you could solve with changing file properties of chromedriver.exe after copying it to a system folder.

**Workaround:** copy the chromedriver.exe to a *non-system* folder like ruby\bin\ and it works.